# How to I convert between monad stacks with transformers in scalaz 7

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, scalaz7

I'm struggling with understanding monad stacks and monad transformers with `Scalaz7`.  I feel I'm pretty close to the answer but just can't get my head around a particular step.

The following code looks on disk for an `ffmpeg` binary, then creates an executable command to be run, then executes that command and then does something trivial with the output.

```
object Encoder {

  def findFfmpeg: OptionT[IO, String] = {
    OptionT[IO, String](IO {
      List("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "/usr/bin/ffmpeg").find {
        new File(_).exists
      }
    }
    )
  }

  def getCommand(ffmpegBin: String,
                 videoFile: String) = s"$ffmpegBin $videoFile  '-vcodec libx264 -s 1024x576' /tmp/out.mp4"

  def callFfmpeg(command: String): IO[Option[Stream[String]]] = IO {
    Some(Process(command).lines_!)
  }

  def getStream(fileName: String): OptionT[IO, Stream[String]] = {
    val optionalCommand: OptionT[IO, String] = findFfmpeg map {
      getCommand(_, fileName)
    }
    optionalCommand >>= {
      command => OptionT[IO, Stream[String]](callFfmpeg(command))
    }
  }

  def encode(fileName: String): IO[Unit] = {
    getStream(fileName) map {
      a: Stream[String] =>
        a map {
          _.length
        } foreach (println)

    } getOrElse (Unit.box {println("nothing")})
  }
}
```

The code is kicked off by running

```
Encoder.encode("/path/to/video.mp4").unsafePerformIO
```

This code works, but you will notice that `callFfmpeg`'s type signature is `IO[Option[Stream[String]]]` instead of `IO[Stream[String]]`.  I had to change it to that to get it to type check, but really since all `callFfmpeg` does is call execute a process which returns a `Stream` it's type signature should be `IO[Stream[String]]`.

My question is, given that at the time I call `callFfmpeg` I'm dealing with `IO[Option[String]]` how do I get to `IO[Option[Stream[String]]]`?

Comment: Why not have `findFfmpeg` return a plain old `IO[Option[String]]` action and then map into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've managed to transform the type by using `liftM[OptionT]`.

So my `callFfmpeg` function can become:

```
def callFfmpeg(command: String): IO[Stream[String]] = IO {
    Process(command).lines_!
}
```

and my `getStream` function now becomes:

```
def getStream(fileName: String): OptionT[IO, Stream[String]] = {
    val optionalCommand: OptionT[IO, String] = findFfmpeg map {
        getCommand(_, fileName)
    }
    optionalCommand >>= {
        command => callFfmpeg(command).liftM[OptionT]
    }
}
```

This allows the conversion from `IO[Stream[String]]` to `IO[Option[Stream[String]]]` which is what I'm after.